# Copying feature service to local geodatabase using ArcPy and ArcGIS API for Python?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, feature-service, arcgis-python-api

I am trying to export/copy a feature service to a local geodatabase where I can work on it locally.

I have provided the code below. I keep getting an "Object: Error in executing tool" for the last line where I am trying to copy the feature.

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features.use_proximity import create_buffers

import arcpy

#########################################################################################

GDB_Name = input("Name Geodatabase")

Folder_Input = input("Provide Folder Path of Project")

Item_ID = input("Provide item ID")


#########################################################################################

gis = GIS("http://arcgis.com", "XXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXX")

search_results = gis.content.search('{}'.format(Item_ID))

Trail_Data = search_results[0]

WorkspaceGDB = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(Folder_Input, '{}.gdb'.format(GDB_Name))
print("GDB created")

arcpy.env.workspace = r'{}'.format(WorkspaceGDB)

arcpy.CopyFeatures(Trail_Data, "Area_Trail_Data")
```

Comment: Simply, your `Trial_Data` is a pointer to an ArcGIS Python API `item`. This is not valid input to the CopyFeatures tool. You're on the right track, but this workflow, as-is will not work without coming at this from another angle.

Comment: I'm going to try and download the "searched item" as a shapefile, then locate the newly downloaded shapefile, and try to copy from there. I will update the post if this workflow works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out. The issue I was having is that I wasn't referencing down all the way to the REST API URL. Once you give it the feature service URL page to your feature service then it works fine.

Code provided below:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS

import arcpy

gis = GIS("http://arcgis.com", "XXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXX")
print("Credentials Verified")


########################################################################################################################

GDB_Name = input("Name Geodatabase: ")

Folder_Input = input("Provide Folder Path of Project: ")

REST_URL_for_Feature = input("Provide : REST Item URL")

Feature_Class_Name = input("Provide Name for New Feature Class: ")

########################################################################################################################

WorkspaceGDB = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(Folder_Input, '{}.gdb'.format(GDB_Name))

arcpy.env.workspace = r'{}'.format(WorkspaceGDB)

print("GDB Created")
########################################################################################################################

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(REST_URL_for_Feature, Feature_Class_Name)

print("Features copied to geodatabase")
print("Process Finished")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using your Trail_Data variable:

```
# select all features
query = Trail_Data.query(where='1=1')

# save selected features to specified geodatabase
query.save("path_to_geodatabase", "new_feature_class_name")
```

I am constantly confused by the ArcGIS API for Python, but from what I gather, your Trail_Data variable is a Feature Collection and the query result is a Feature Set. The Feature Set can be saved directly to a file geodatabase.